# Upgrading Android Studio Gradle to 6.1.1 breaks Greendao3GradlePlugin

Tags: android, gradle, greendao

This morning I upgraded Android Studio to use Gradle 6.1.1.

Now, my attempts to build fail with the following error:

> Unable to find method
>   'org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskInputs.property(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs;'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include: Gradle's dependency
>   cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection
>   timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping
>   all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build processes
>   (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible
>   with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle
>   requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the
>   IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I used [Gradle Build Scan](https://scans.gradle.com/s/56rkop7yk3jn4/) to find the issue.

The issue is with the `Greendao3GradlePlugin` third party plugin.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should update `Greendao` to the lastest version

```
// In your root build.gradle file:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral() // add repository
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.3.0' // add plugin
    }
}

// In your app projects build.gradle file:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao' // apply plugin

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.3.0' // add library
}
```

Check `Greendao` release notes [here](https://greenrobot.org/greendao/changelog/)

Comment: Thank you. I upgraded to 3.3.0 and the problem resolved.